# Set RippleDrawable corner radius programmatically

Tags: android, drawable, rippledrawable

I create a `RippleDrawable` like below. But I can't change the corner radius of the RippleDrawable. 
It doesn't have a method like `setCornerRadii(float[] f)`.

```
public static RippleDrawable getPressedColorRippleDrawable(int normalColor, int pressedColor) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=21) {
        RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = new RippleDrawable(getPressedColorSelector(normalColor, pressedColor), getColorDrawableFromColor(normalColor), null);
        //rippleDrawable.setRadius((int) Manager.convertDpToPixel(5));
        return rippleDrawable;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

And the other functions are

```
public static ColorStateList getPressedColorSelector(int normalColor, int pressedColor) {
    return new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]
                    {
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused},
                            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_activated},
                            new int[]{}
                    },
            new int[]
                    {
                            pressedColor,
                            pressedColor,
                            pressedColor,
                            normalColor
                    }
    );
}

public static ColorDrawable getColorDrawableFromColor(int color) {
    return new ColorDrawable(color);
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why can't you do it in xml?

Comment: @billynomates 'Cause I'm retrieving the RGB color code from server for A/B testing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same issue as you: how to set a corner radius to a *RippleDrawable*.

A simple manner to proceed is to use a `GradientDrawable`. You can set a radius with `setCornerRadius` and then pass the configured instance as the second parameter of the `RippleDrawable` constructor.

Here is an example:

```
ColorStateList pressedStates = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLUE);

GradientDrawable contentDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
contentDrawable.setColor(Color.WHITE);
contentDrawable.setCornerRadius(16);

RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = new RippleDrawable(pressedStates, contentDrawable, null);
container.setBackground(rippleDrawable);
```